# python selenium scrape href (link) from website

Tags: python, selenium

I have this site https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&siteid=5012&PageType=searchResults&SearchType=linkquery&LinkID=6017#keyWordSearch=&locationSearch=

I want to scrape the link for each job role, the HTML source for one of the roles is:

```
<a id="Job_1" href="https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&amp;siteid=5012&amp;PageType=JobDetails&amp;jobid=223876" ng-class="oQ.ClassName" class="jobProperty jobtitle" ng-click="handlers.jobClick($event, this)" ng-bind-html="$root.utils.htmlEncode(oQ.Value)">Technology Delivery Lead (IB Technology)</a>
```

I have tried this:

```
job_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".jobProperty.jobtitle ['href']")


for job_link in job_link:
    job_link = job_link.text
    print(job_link)
```

But it simply returns nothing, can someone kindly help

Comment: Try removing the space between jobtitle and ['href']

Comment: Seeing this error selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Sorry, yes, remove the quotes around href

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at beautiful soup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just print out it's href tag by get_attribute.

```
job_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".jobProperty.jobtitle")

for job_link in job_link:
    print(job_link.get_attribute('href'))
```